# Make blur effect with CSS in a div content

Tags: css

Hi every one

I'm working with a figma design and I'm trying to get a blur effect in a div conteiner like this:

[image]

I tried make this effect with the next rule:

```
background-color: rgba(165, 165, 165, 0.3);
```

But I got this result:

[image]

If I use the filter blur property I get this:

[image]

How could I apply the blur effect in the image behind the div? but no in all the image, just in the part of the div cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern browsers, you can use the `backdrop-filter` property and set it like this:

```css
backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
```

For compatibility, see: https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter

Comment: I tried with this but i get no valid property error  i'm using firefox 96.0 wich elements are compatible with this property?